# C# declare Enum and use it in function but i got CS0120

Tags: c#

i have a namespace called "NameSpace":

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace NameSpace
{
    public enum Number
    {
        One,
        Two,
        Three
    }
    public sealed class Test1
    {
        public string test(Number num)
        {
            switch (num)
            {
                case Number.One:
                    return "1";
                case Number.Two:
                    return "2";
                case Number.Three:
                    return "3";
            }
            return "?";
        }
    }
}
```

and when I call this line :

```
Console.WriteLine(NameSpace.Test1.test(NameSpace.Number.One));
```

and I get a error :

> error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `NameSpace.Test1.test(NameSpace.Number)'

Someone can help me ? thank you vary much !

Comment: The complaint is about `Test1`, not the enum. `test` isn't a static method, so you need to create a `Test1` instance before you can call `test`.

Comment: `Test1.test` is an instance method while you try to access it as static member. You need to either instantiate `Test1` class or make `test` method static.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options:

You can make `test` a `static method:

```
public static string test(Number num) { /*...*/ }
```

Then you don't need an instance of `Test1` but an call `test` on the type:

```
Test1.test(Number.One);
```

Or you need to create an instance of your `Test1` class:

```
Test1 instance = new Test1();
instance.test(Number.One);
```

---

Since the `test` method does not use any *instance members* of `Test1`, the first approach is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
Console.WriteLine(new NameSpace.Test1().test(NameSpace.Number.One));
```

or make the method static:

```
public static string test(Number num)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to first make an object of class Test1 and then call the test method on it

```
Console.WriteLine(new Test1().test(NameSpace.Number.One));
```

Comment: You forgot about `new` keyword at the beginning

Comment: True that, I edited it. I am using swift these days haha

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you've not declared the test method as static. You'll have to add the `static` keyword to the method declaration such as `public static string test...` or create new instance of the `Test1` class.

```
Test1 t = new Test1();
Console.WriteLine(t.test(Number.One));
```

You should read more about [static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) and [object-oriented programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656686.aspx).